# Solr Query Execution

Tags: java, solr, full-text-search, field, edismax

How will a query like below will get executed, In which order

I understand that when this query is executed fields mentioned in fieldList will be returned. What I don't understand is how the "samplestring1" and "samplestring2" will get searched with the query fields specified

I think I will be able to understand how the search happens if this can be illustrated in SQL ( Just to understand what happens behind the scene)

Following is the query. Please have a look at it and let me know how this works internally.
query=samplestring1 AND samplestring2
defType: edismax
queryFields: Exact_Field1^1.0 Exact_Field2^0.9 Field1^0.8 Field2^0.7
fieldList: Column1, Column2
resultRows: 10
startRow: 0

P.S samplestring1 AND samplestring2  are some test strings in the query

Sample of Schema for fields

```xml
<fieldType name="sampletype1" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="5" maxGramSize="10"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldtype name="sampletype2" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">   
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldtype>

<field name="Field1" compressed="true" type="sampletype1" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<field name="Field2" compressed="true" type="sampletype1" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<field name="Exact_Field1" omitPositions="true" termVectors="false" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" compressed="true" type="sampletype2" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<field name="Exact_Field2" omitPositions="true" termVectors="false" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" compressed="true" type="sampletype2" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" omitNorms="true"/>

<copyField source="Field1" dest="Exact_Field1"/>
<copyField source="Field2" dest="Exact_Field2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL and solr are very different. What I suggest you do, is to add `&debugQuery=on` parametar to your query url and this will give you the ParsedQuery in the output, so you can know how it generate the parsed Query internally.